# System.ArgumentException HResult=0x80070057 Message=Stream is now writable Parameter name: stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

I have asp.net core 2 web api endpoint along with custom middleware. In order to accomplish the centralized exception handling and request validation for the project I referred the link: https://www.strathweb.com/2018/07/centralized-exception-handling-and-request-validation-in-asp-net-core/

Based on the reference I implemented the following code :

```
// Startup

public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseGraphiQl();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
        {
            errorApp.Run(async context =>
            {
                var errorFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                var exception = errorFeature.Error;
                // the IsTrusted() extension method doesn't exist and
                // you should implement your own as you may want to interpret it differently
                // i.e. based on the current principal
                var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails{Instance = $"urn:myorganization:error:{Guid.NewGuid()}"};
                if (exception is BadHttpRequestException badHttpRequestException)
                {
                    problemDetails.Title = "Invalid request";
                    problemDetails.Status = (int)typeof (BadHttpRequestException).GetProperty("StatusCode", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(badHttpRequestException);
                    problemDetails.Detail = badHttpRequestException.Message;
                }
                else
                {
                    problemDetails.Title = "An unexpected error occurred!";
                    problemDetails.Status = 500;
                    problemDetails.Detail = "Testing"; //exception.Demystify().ToString();
                }

                // log the exception etc..
                context.Response.StatusCode = problemDetails.Status.Value;
                context.Response.WriteJson(problemDetails, "application/problem+json");
            }

            );
        }

        );
        app.UseCommonResponser();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
// CommonResponseMiddleware

public class CommonResponseMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private ICommonService _commonService;
    public CommonResponseMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ICommonService commonService)
    {
        _next = next;
        _commonService = commonService;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var currentBody = context.Response.Body;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            context.Response.Body = memoryStream;
            await _next.Invoke(context);
            context.Response.Body = currentBody;
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var readToEnd = new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
} 

   // GraphQLController

[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class GraphQLController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDocumentExecuter _documentExecuter;
    private readonly ISchema _schema;
    public GraphQLController(ISchema schema, IDocumentExecuter documentExecuter)
    {
        _schema = schema;
        _documentExecuter = documentExecuter;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] GraphQLQuery query)
    {
        if (query == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(query));
        }

        var inputs = query.Variables.ToInputs();
        var executionOptions = new ExecutionOptions{Schema = _schema, Query = query.Query, Inputs = inputs, UserContext = Request.Headers, //UserContext = new GraphQLUserContext { Headers = Request.Headers }
        };
        throw new Exception("Exception while fetching all the students from the storage.");
        var result = await _documentExecuter.ExecuteAsync(executionOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (result.Errors?.Count > 0)
        {
            return BadRequest(result);
        }

        return Ok(result);
    }
}

// HttpExtensions

public static class HttpExtensions
{
    private static readonly JsonSerializer Serializer = new JsonSerializer{NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore};
    public static void WriteJson<T>(this HttpResponse response, T obj, string contentType = null)
    {
        response.ContentType = contentType ?? "application/json";
        using (var writer = new HttpResponseStreamWriter(response.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
            {
                jsonWriter.CloseOutput = false;
                jsonWriter.AutoCompleteOnClose = false;
                Serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now on invoking the graphqlcontroller endpoint, I am intentionally throwing an error which I am trying to catch in the global exception logic where I am trying to customize it before passing it to the customer.

I am getting an exception: Stream is now writable Parameter name: stream, while processing it in the HttpExtensions class at the below line:

```
using (var writer = new HttpResponseStreamWriter(response.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Here is my finding: Whenever any exception thrown at controller level it bubbles upto  await _next.Invoke(context); and from there on the memorysteam gets disposed and not available while writing the response using WriteJson method. Hence on trying to write the response it is throwing an error. I tried to remove the using() block for the memorystream, with this change the memorystream is available, but the response is not getting thrown the browser. Any help on this is much appreciated